# Merge Document issue using AltChunk or OpenXmlPowerTool

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-powertools

I have tried to use AltChunk and OpenXmlPowerTool for merging some documents, but there are 2 different serious problems I cannot solve.

(1) For using AltChunk, some page setup may be disappeared or reset to default, like orientation and page margin. Usually, the disappeared page setup is the extra paragraph with section properies .

(2) For using OpenXmlPowerTool, same styleId issue may makes the document strange. If rename all styleId as unique in all source document, it may exceed the maximum limit of styleId (max. 4,000 styleId).

Anyone can solve either one?